# The evaluation of a scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

This may be a stupid question.
I notice that we use scope resolution operator `::` for both a namespace and a static member function.

1)
`std::printf("foo");`

2)
`MyClass::foo();`

Here are my questions:
1. How could a C++ compiler differentiate them?
2. What is the process of a C++ compiler when it sees a scope resolution operator?

Comment: For your first question, in the examples you show it's all about context. Your second question is way to broad to explain here on SO, and will be hard to do to anyone without some knowledge about how compilers work.

Comment: Is there a case that we use a class function without instantiating an object like java?

Comment: Only `static` member functions.

Comment: I modified the question a little bit. I am talking about a static member function.

Comment: Even after your edits, the second example is not calling a static member function. It still looks more like a member function definition.

Comment: In these examples, the compiler will have to know what the name in front of the `::` means, so it has to have seen its declaration earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gory details are in *3.4.3 Qualified name lookup* of the C++ spec (with *3.3.1 Declarative regions and scopes* and *5.1.1 (Primary expressions) General* also providing some useful information.)

To boil it down, though, both namespaces and classes are "declarative regions", so in your example, `std::cout` refers to the name `cout` in the declarative region named `std`, and `MyClass::foo` refers to the name `foo` in the declarative region named `MyClass`. As far as the `::` operator is concerned, namespaces and classes are the "same sort of thing".

In addition, because names must be unique within a declarative region (including the global namespace), the following code is invalid:

```
//invalid code - does not compile
namespace test { int x; }
class test { static int x; };
```

In other words, there is no ambiguity between `test::x` referring to the x in the namespace or the x in the class.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.